# checking whether the label of views fields is excluded from display?

Tags: views

I am writing a views style plugin . I want to check whether the fields of views has its checkbox of label exclude form display has been checked or not . I tried doing dsm($variables) , but dint found the variable that can give me some idea about the same. Can someone help please?

Comment: Your after the '#label_display' property of a field.

Comment: did you mean in $variables['view']->field . But i cannot find that there . Can you please elaborate